# SQL Query takes longer using With compared to subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, dbeaver

I am a little perplexed why a simple SQL query using with clauses takes so much longer than putting them in subqueries. An instance on my IDE for >10mil records runs >30mins using with clause and only <10sec using subqueries.

Will just list a simple example below:

```
with table1 as (select tb1.a, tb1.b, tb2.c, tb3.d
                from tablea
                where a > 0 and b = 2016)
     table2 as (select a, b, c, d, e, f
                from table1 tb1
                left join table2 tb2 on tb1.a=tb2.a
                left join table3 tb3 on tb1.b=tb2.b)
select * from table2
```

Compared to putting them as subqueries instead:

```
select * from (select a, b, c, d, e, f
                from (select tb1.a, tb1.b, tb2.c, tb3.d
                      from tablea
                      where a > 0 and b = 2016) tb1
                left join table2 tb2 on tb1.a=tb2.a
                left join table3 tb3 on tb1.b=tb2.b) table2
```

The latter query completes much faster than the former. However, the former is much easier on the eyes on the query structure, so I would prefer that if possible.

I wonder the huge discrepancy is due to the IDE I used (DBeaver) in interpreting, or it is based on the SQL statement logic itself?

Thank you.

Comment: please provide execution plans for both

Comment: This is called the 'optimisation fence behaviour of postgresql`. I am sure it's on dba.stackexchange.

Comment: By the way, this might go away in v11 if somebody does the work. [This lengthy thread](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/5351711493487900%40web53g.yandex.ru#5351711493487900@web53g.yandex.ru) on the hackers list has more or less reached consensus to do away with it an introduce a `MATERIALIZED` keyword that allows you to explicitly choose the old behaviour.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I've followed the discussion on the mailing list. IMHO a better naming would be `NOT MATERIALIZED` , because the standard CTEs already act as if materialized , especially if referenced more than once.

Comment: Not all CTEs can be inlined. For those that cannot, the behaviour will stay the same. The new behaviour would be to inline wherever possible unless `MATERIALIZED` is used. Basically, the keyword means "behave as in old versions" and is kind of a query hint.

Comment: I realise that. I am only complaining that the word `MATERIALIZED` is a bad choice, because the behaviour is exactly the contrary. It should be `inline` or `volatile` or `view` or maybe even `lateral`. I realize that the developers dont like to introduce new keywords, so reusing existing keywords is almost mandatory.

Comment: Thanks all, this is all new to me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because in Postgres CTEs act as optimisation barriers. A workaround (with almost the same syntactic structure) is to replace the CTEs by `TEMP VIEW`s :

---

```
CREATE TEMP VIEW v1 AS
        SELECT ta.a, ta.b, ta.c, ta.d
        FROM tablea ta
        WHERE a > 0 and b = 2016
        ;
CREATE TEMP VIEW v2 AS
        SELECT a, b, c, d, e, f
        FROM v1
        LEFT JOIN table2 tb2 ON v1.a=tb2.a
        LEFT JOIN table3 tb3 ON v1.b=tb3.b
        ;
SELECT * from v2;
```